# Is it possible to upvote or downvote a deleted answer on stack overflow?

Tags: bug, voting

I know its unbelievable but accidentally I downvoted this deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456652/2455888) (10K+ users only) and the down vote is recorded with the message

```
This post has been deleted; deleted post can't be voted on
```

which should't. Previous it had 3 downvotes and now it is showing 4. I don't have before and after picture to prove what I am claiming is true but it happened and I am surprised! May be some moderator can confirm what I am saying is true.

Comment: If you look in your list of votes, does the post appear there? Do you see any reputation changes from the voting?

Comment: According to the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29456652/timeline) (10K+), all four votes were cast on 2015-04-05, before the question was deleted.

Comment: @TZHX; No. There is no change in my reputation. It should be decreased by 1.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi; I swear that there was 3 downvotes on that question. 4th was casted today, but the problem is that I have nothing to prove it.

Comment: Your profile indicates a single vote for today. Have you voted on anything else?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi; I upvoted only one [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35030288/2455888) today.

Comment: Caching? How long had the tab been open before you clicked to vote? (Were you looking at an outdated version of the page)

Comment: @Sayse; Approximately 5-10 minutes. I just got an upvote on my answer there and visited that page and it happened at that time.

Answer (score 4):

That post has had 4 downvotes since the day it was posted:

[image: daily vote summary]

There are no other daily summaries in the post timeline, and it was deleted that same day.

You must remember wrong. You indeed can't vote on posts that have been deleted.

Comment: I wish I had some screen shot to prove my ground.